# После обработки формы перезагружать страницу без get параметров

Tags: ajax, html, get

Вот форма

```
if(isset($_GET['add_url']))
    {   
        $url=$_GET['url'];
        $description=$_GET['description'];
        $url=mysql_real_escape_string($url);
        $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO short_url VALUES('','$user_id','$url','','$description') ")or die(mysql_error());
//берем последний айди
        $l_id=mysql_insert_id();
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE short_url SET short_url='$l_id' WHERE id='$l_id' ");
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT short_url FROM short_url WHERE id='$l_id' ")or die(mysql_error());
            $result=mysql_fetch_array($query);
            $result="http://localhost/r/?".$result['short_url'];
                if($query){
                echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){
                                            $('.view-copy').show();
                    }
                    );
                    </script>";
                }                   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

передавать данные через POST

Comment: @mountpoint
url же не поддерживается POST?

Comment: @Анатолийй, какую ссылку в урле вы хотите получить в итоге? Опишите более детально вашу проблему